# size of program header table and section header table for 32 bit/64 bit ELF binaries

Tags: linux, elf

Size of ELF header for 32 bit and 64 bit ELF binary is 52 and 64 bytes respectively. I was wondering if the size of program header table or section header table is also defined and fixed for 32 bit and 64 bit ELF binaries?

I have some ELF files where size of program header table for all 32-bit and 64-bit binaries is 32 bytes and 56 bytes respectively. Similarly, the size of section header table for all 32-bit and 64-bit binary is 40 bytes and 64 bytes respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if the size of program header table or section header table is also defined and fixed for 32 bit and 64 bit ELF binaries?

The size of 1 *element* in each of these tables is fixed (`sizeof(Elf{32,64}_Phdr)`, `sizeof(Elf{32,64}_Shdr)`), but the *total* size of these tables depends on the number of segments and sections, and these numbers are highly variable between different binaries.